# Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ) w/ Jest & React Native

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babeljs

I'm attempting to use jest (v19.0.2) w/ my react native (v0.38.0) project however when I run the jest command I'm receiving the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/kyledecot/code/root-react-native/node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:40
      )
      ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

      at transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/transform.js:320:12)
      at handle (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:41:8)
      at process.<anonymous> (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:47:3)
      at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
```

Here's the file it's complaining about:

```
 30   .mock('ReactNativeDefaultInjection')
 31   .mock('Image', () => mockComponent('Image'))
 32   .mock('Text', () => mockComponent('Text'))
 33   .mock('TextInput', () => mockComponent('TextInput'))
 34   .mock('Modal', () => mockComponent('Modal'))
 35   .mock('View', () => mockComponent('View'))
 36   .mock('ScrollView', () => mockComponent('ScrollView'))
 37   .mock(
 38     'ActivityIndicator',
 39     () => mockComponent('ActivityIndicator'),
 40   )
 41   .mock('ListView', () => {
 42     const RealListView = require.requireActual('ListView');
 43     const ListView = mockComponent('ListView');
 44     ListView.prototype.render = RealListView.prototype.render;
 45     return ListView;
 46   })
 47   .mock('ListViewDataSource', () => {
 48     const DataSource = require.requireActual('ListViewDataSource');
 49     DataSource.prototype.toJSON = function() {
 50       function ListViewDataSource(dataBlob) {
```

Has anyone else ran into this bug or know how I would go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this nearly a year later so I can't verify if this fix would work on those versions but I ran into the same issue with React Native 53, Jest 21 and TypeScript 2.7

My solution has 3 parts:

1. your `package.json`, add the following to your jest config:

```

```
{
    jest: {
        "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js", "json"],
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
            "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/preprocessor.js"
        },
    }
}
```

```

2. in your root folder (see path above), create a `preprocessor.js` file with the following contents (note the use of your existing `tsconfig.json` file):

```

```
const tsc = require('react-native-typescript-transformer');
const tsConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');

module.exports = {
    process(src, filename) {
        if (filename.match(/\.png/)) {
            return '';
        }
        if (filename.endsWith('.ts') || filename.endsWith('.tsx')) {
            return tsc.transform(src, filename, tsConfig.compilerOptions);
        }
        return src;
    },
};
```

```

3. use `npm install --S react-native-typescript-transformer` to install the transformer library