# Unexpected token ')' in jest-haste-map node module

Tags: react-native, jestjs

Jest is currently throwing the following error when I try to run my tests:

```
/Users/harrycondron/developer/marketplace/app/partner/marketplace/node_modules/react-native/jest/hasteImpl.js:50
 ) /*: string | void */ {
 ^

   SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
   at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
   at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
   at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
   at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/harrycondron/developer/marketplace/app/partner/marketplace/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js:19:19)
```

my Jest version is "23.3.0"

any help is appreciated

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529402/syntax-error-unexpected-token-w-jest-react-native) help?